# Определение местонахождения человека через API Яндекс.Карт

Tags: javascript

Здравствуйте.

Пытаюсь посредством встраиваемого кода на сайт определить некоторые данные человека например, где он находится (город, страна).

```
function geopotision(){
    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.src = "http://api-maps.yandex.ru/2.0/?load=package.full&lang=ru-RU";
    document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(script);

    var map;
    var city, country;

    ymaps.ready(init);
    function init () {
        var geolocation = ymaps.geolocation;
        city    = geolocation.city;
        country = geolocation.country;

        // console.log(city);
        // console.log(country);
    }

}
```

в панеле браузера пишет: Uncaught ReferenceError: ymaps is not defined

**Что делать подскажите?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

У вас скрипт не успевает подгружаться. Попробуйте так

```
function geopotision(){
    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.src = "http://api-maps.yandex.ru/2.0/?load=package.full&lang=ru-RU";
    document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(script);

    var map;
    var city, country;

    function init () {
        if (typeof ymaps === 'undefined' || typeof ymaps.geolocation === 'undefined') {
            setTimeout(init, 100);
            return;
        }
        var geolocation = ymaps.geolocation;
        city    = geolocation.city;
        country = geolocation.country;

        console.log(city);
        console.log(country);
    }

    init();
}
```

Comment: спасибо за решение.